# Does Realm Mobile Platform suit to manage service for small companies?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, realm

I am developing an application to manage small companies (1-2 managers and 20-100 employees). A manager has a Mac application for managers. Each employee has `iPad` with an app for employees. I would like to try use Realm Mobile Platform for this purpose. But I can't imagine architecture. 
The idea is the following:

- Manager can create some common data shared with all employees (shared
  realms with access granted to all employees?).
- Each employee can create private data (private shared realm with ~ symbol?).
- Manager can see in his app all common data as well as all private data (all common realms and all employees' private `realms`?)

E.g. I create these 2 applications and distribute them to small companies (e.g. 300 companies). Should I set up a separate `Realm Object` Server for each company (not best solution) or I can use one `Realm Object Server` containing `Realms` for all companies? And how in this case to grant access to the company specific `Realms` only to its managers and employees?

As `Realm` replicates the whole database, manager will have all Realms on his Mac and each employee will have common `Realms` and 1 private Realm on his `iPad`, right? I am wondering because each `Realm` may have size ~40 Mb. Therefore I don't want to replicate all company's data (actually all common and `private Realms`) to each `iPad`.

Answer (score 2):

> Manager can create some common data shared with all employees (shared realms with access granted to all employees?).

This could be a single realm shared with all employees.

> Each employee can create private data (private shared realm with ~ symbol?).

Using the `~` tilde in front of the Realms URL is just for namespacing (it get replaced with the userid). It is similar how you would address the users homedir in a filesystem. By default users can only create realms in their own namespace.

But even if realms are created in the users own namespace (where only they have access to it by default), you can still add extra permissions to share it with others. So in your case you would just add permissions to allow the manager to read them as well.

> Should I set up a separate Realm Object Server for each company (not best solution) or I can use one Realm Object Server containing Realms for all companies?

You can do both. Using one server per company will make scaling easy (and you can host it in an availability zone close to their actual location), but you could also host it all on one server.

Since the individual employees all stores their realms under their own namespace (`realm://host.com/~/myrealm`) there will be no conflicts there. For the managers shared realms you could just put them each under a company namespace (`realm://host.com/companyname/sharedrealm`).

> As Realm replicates the whole database, manager will have all Realms on his Mac

The manager does not need to have all the employee realms on his Mac all the time, they can be opened on demand when needed.

> how in this case to grant access to the company specific Realms only to its managers and employees?

Currently you need the Enterprise edition to control individual permissions like that (but it is coming to the Developer Edition as well), so you should contact us

Comment: Thanks ast, this is exactly what I wanted to know.